# Automate Remote Control of Computer in SCCM

Tags: powershell, sccm

How can I automatically open up a bunch of remote control sessions and log on to each one given a list of computers?

I've tried the following (taken from http://ccmexec.com/2012/05/running-configuration-manager-2012-remote-control-standalone/):

```
.\CmRcViewer.exe 'computerName'
```

However I still need to click on Action -> 'Send Ctrl+Alt+Del Key', then type in my username/password.

I'd like to automatically log on to each computer.

I can't use mstsc because Remote Desktop is not enabled on the computers.

Comment: [Build an RDCMan (Remote Desktop Connection Manager) Config File](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/49207d61-721d-4522-879b-2634d2d02cc6) seems to be a possible solution (instead of popping up multiple RDP Sessions).

Answer (score 2):

The Remote Control in SCCM can be used from command line with `CmRcViewer.exe` it will accept a netbios name as a parameter. Credentials will be inherited.  Perhaps it will be possible to change to other credentials using runas. You can then build a wrapper function for this in Powershell.

CmRCViewer.exe comes with the SCCM admin console, but you can extract it according to this post: http://ccmexec.com/2012/05/running-configuration-manager-2012-remote-control-standalone/

Comment: As far as I know all these credentials are just to verify if the user has the right to access a computer remotely. Once connected you always take over the local session. So only if there is already a user logged in you can access without username and pwd. If no user is logged in you get to the login screen and thus have to enter username and pwd. If you have full control over those remote computers you can configure them to autologin LOCALLY and bypass this issue. Keep in mind that by default if someone is logged in he has to approve but this can be changed in the client settings.

Comment: That is true, the poster changed his original question after I posted this. I was assuming that he meant the credentials needed to access SCCM Remote Control.